# Adding validation to dynamic forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, forms, validation

I pull what to display on a particular form from my database, so the form elements are dynamic.

I display radio buttons, or checkboxes or textboxes/textareas depending on how I want the form to display.

Before someone submits the form, I have to validate that each form entry (radio, checkbox, textbox etc) has been selected.

**How can I insert validation to these dynamic form elements?**

Example:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="@formInputId" name="@formInputName" value="@element.Id"  />
```

Comment: How is it dynamic? your view is based on a model with specific properties, isn't it?

Comment: you mean jquery validation?only on client side?

Comment: @AbbasAmiri Yes I have a strongly typed viewmodel, like I loop through them like `@foreach (FormElement element in Model.FormElements)` but the # of elements comes from the database.  Yes validation on the client side is what I am looking for.

Comment: @user1361315 I recommend to you using HtmlHelpers, they make your view clean and easy to maintain and I can't see any problem of using them with your scenario. Validation is completely supported by HtmlHelpers.

Comment: I'll look into that, but for now it isn't using htmlhelpers, how can I do it manually?

Comment: `$('#form01').validate(); $('#form02').validate(); ` will this not work ?

Comment: show this exemples
http://speckyboy.com/2009/12/17/10-useful-jquery-form-validation-techniques-and-tutorials-2/

Comment: validatefor and validation summary and validate html helpers extension methods are there.. use that

Answer (score 4):

to get started, you can also inject JSON/Javascript into the view. Though this is not preffered because then you wont be able to make a separate js file out of it. But in case of validation of dynamic forms i did this earlier.

since your form ids are coming from the database you know Id of each control therefore you can identify each element separately using jquery.

[jquery validation plugins](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) makes it very easy to add validation rules. So you just make the validation rules server side with something like this.

```
forEach(FormElement element in Model.FormElements){
 dynamic rules = new ExpandoObject();
 //set all the rule here.
 ViewBag.ElementId = rules;
}
```

basic rules structure is given [here](http://jqueryvalidation.org/rules/).

Then inside the view when you are rendering the controls. check for

```
@if(ViewData.ContainsKey("[ElementId]")){
//if it exists
//inject json using newtonsoft json
<script>
$('#@Html.raw([ElementId])').rules("Add", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ViewData["ElementId"]))
</script>
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at the jquery validation plugin? Why try to reinvent the wheel. It's pretty simple to use.

Check this [Demo](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/)

Here is the link to the official docs. http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/

Answer (score 1):

**Html**

```
<form id="myform">
<input name="product[0][name]" id="form_product[0][name]" data-rule-required="true" />
<input name="product[1][name]" id="form_product[1][name]" data-rule-required="true" />
<input name="product[2][name]" id="form_product[2][name]" data-rule-required="true" />
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<input type="submit" />
```

add one field
Validation Documentation

**css**

```
#docs {
display: block;
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
```

}

**js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin      
    submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
        alert('valid form submitted'); // for demo
        return false; // for demo
    }
});

$('button').one('click', function () {
    $('#myform').append('<input name="product[3][name]" id="form_product[3][name]" data-rule-required="true">');
});});
```

[**DEMO jsfiddle HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/WVbmj/)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to [parse the elements](http://xhalent.wordpress.com/2011/01/24/applying-unobtrusive-validation-to-dynamic-content/) dynamically with the unobtrusive validation, however you'll need to add the appropriate attributes to trigger the appropriate validation first. Fundamentally it's very similar to what's happening in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6691958/332733) where they are adding elements dynamically by javascript.

Answer (score 0):

If you can output a json blob of validations you can use this: https://github.com/parris/iz#json

It will let you specify a JSON blob of rules as such:

```
var rules = {
    'cost': [
        {
            'rule': 'between',
            'args': [17, 1000],
            'error': 'The cost must be between 17, 1000'
        },
        {
            'rule': 'required',
            'error': 'You must specify a cost'
        },
    ],
    'producer.id': [
        {
            'rule': 'int',
            'error': 'Producer ID must be an int'
        }
    ],
    'producer.name.first': [
        {
            'rule': 'alphaNumeric',
            'error': 'Must be names and numbers'
        }
    ]
};
```

Then collect your values and validate like this:

```
are(rules).validFor({
    cost: 20,
    producer: {
        id: 1,
        name: {
            first: 'bob'
        }
    }
});
```

It has some built in validations that should pretty closely match what you need. If not, you can shim in some custom validations.

Note: Iz, is a library I wrote, and yes I am totally pitching it to you right now.

Answer (score 0):

The JQuery Validate plugin should work (see http://jqueryvalidation.org).

It sounds like all you need is to mark all fields required, so you can add a required rule to them by using a class, which would avoid having to coordinate ids/names of your dynamic elements between the model and the javascript.

Change your input line to:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="@formInputId" name="@formInputName" 
    value="@element.Id" class="requiredField" />
```

Then in your javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var form = $( "#MyForm" );
    form.validate();

    jQuery.validator.addClassRules('requiredField', {
        required: true
    });

    form.on('submit', function () {
        if (form.valid()) {
            form.submit();
        }
    });
});
```

You can also check validity of individual elements by using `(selector).valid()`. You can add other validation rules (besides required) by adding to the list of class rules.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [Jquery Validate engine](http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/) .

In which, you just have to manage class attribute of the dynamic element.

I suggest you, you could use [Hook of Jquery Validate Engine](http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/demos/demoHooks.html).

It will be easy for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently answered a question where we do no of things with jQuery, if you want to user custom jQuery, take reference as follows:

On form element you can use recursive code for ex: in case of a checkbox

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#new_user_form *').filter(':checkbox').each(function(){
        if(this.id=='row1' && this.value=='3') {
        } else {
            $(this).attr("checked",false);
        }
    });
});
```

Will work same for other type of element i.e input, radio etc.

[On selecting a checkbox disable spefic checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18912096/on-selecting-a-checkbox-disable-spefic-checkboxes/18913592#18913592)

Review above for more, comment for more info or a small demo form.

Answer (score 0):

i have achieved the same requirement using [jQuery Validation Plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/)

Place the following code in script section of your page.
you need to add the `form-data` class to your form and add `required_field` while adding the elements to page.

```
var validator = null;
$(document).ready(function () {
    try {
        var validatedForm = $(".form-data");
        validator = validatedForm.validate && validatedForm.validate({
            rules: {
                required_field: {
                    required: true
                }
            },
            messages: {
                required_field: {
                    required: " "
                }
            },
            errorElement: "span",
            showErrors: function (errorMap, errorList) {
                this.defaultShowErrors();
            },
            highlight: function (element) {
                // do something like
                $(element).closest('...').removeClass('success').addClass('error');
            },
            unhighlight: function (element) {
                // do something like
                $(element).closest('...').removeClass('error');
            },
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                // submit form
                form.submit();
            }
            success: function (element) {
                // do something like
                $(element).closest('...').removeClass('error').end().remove();
            },
            onfocusout: function (element) {
                $(element).valid();
            },
        });

        $.each($(".required_field"), function (index, value){
            $(value).rules( "add", {
                  required: true,
                  messages: {
                      required: " "
                  }
            });
        });
    } catch(err) {
        console.log("javascript error", err);
    }
});
```

While submitting you can check if the form is valid or not:

```
if($('#formId').valid()) {
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

i guess the best way is make your client-side validation using $.validate plugin and in your POST action create methods to validate your data. I always suggest to not mix javascript with csharp, or others places, to maintains things organized.