# On selecting a checkbox disable spefic checkboxes

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

I have a table of checkboxes, on selecting a certain checkbox I need to disable specific checkboxes. I can do this with jquery but I'm having trouble with distinguishing between the checkboxes present in my table.

Here's my code:

```
<table id="mytb" class="table table-hover table-condensed">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="width: 25%;">Column 1</th>
                <th style="width: 25%">Column 2</th>
                <th style="width: 25%">Column 3</th>
                <th style="width: 25%">Column 4</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Row 1</td>
                <td class="vcenter"><input type="checkbox" id="row1" value="1"/></td>
        <td class="vcenter"><input type="checkbox" id="row1" value="2"/></td>
        <td class="vcenter"><input type="checkbox" id="row1" value="3"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Row 2</td>
                <td class="vcenter"><input type="checkbox" id="row2" value="1"/></td>
        <td class="vcenter"><input type="checkbox" id="row2" value="2"/></td>
        <td class="vcenter"><input type="checkbox" id="row2" value="3"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Row 3</td>
                <td class="vcenter"><input type="checkbox" id="row3" value="1"/></td>
        <td class="vcenter"><input type="checkbox" id="row3" value="2"/></td>
        <td class="vcenter"><input type="checkbox" id="row3" value="3"/></td>
            </tr>
<tr>
                <td>Row 4</td>
                <td class="vcenter"><input type="checkbox" id="row4" value="1"/></td>
        <td class="vcenter"><input type="checkbox" id="row4" value="2"/></td>
        <td class="vcenter"><input type="checkbox" id="row4" value="3"/></td>
            </tr>
<tr>
                <td>Row 5</td>
                <td class="vcenter"><input type="checkbox" id="row5" value="1"/></td>
        <td class="vcenter"><input type="checkbox" id="row5" value="2"/></td>
        <td class="vcenter"><input type="checkbox" id="row5" value="3"/></td>
            </tr>
<tr>
                <td>Row 6</td>
                <td class="vcenter"><input type="checkbox" id="row6" value="1"/></td>
        <td class="vcenter"><input type="checkbox" id="row6" value="2"/></td>
        <td class="vcenter"><input type="checkbox" id=row6" value="3"/></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

So here are my conditions:

1. If I select the checkbox with id="row1" value="3", I need to disable all the other check boxes present.
2. If I select a checkbox from any other row, that is row 2,3,4,5 or 6 where value=3 then I need to disable all the other checkboxes in the same row(where the values associated are 1 and 2).
3. If I select a checkbox from any other row, that is row 2,3,4,5 or 6 where value=2 then I need to disable the checkbox in the same row where value=1.

Comment: It is not good idea to put same id for multiple items

Comment: Do you already have any JS code? And I would maybe start with having ids/classes on the rows if I wanted to accomplish what you want... ;)

Comment: I could change that to matrix like values indicating the position of the checkbox in the table but how do I specifically identify a checkbox when I'm calling jquery? Like how do I identify for example the checkbox with the attributes {id="row1" value="3"} so I can call and see whether it is checked or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add following code to the jQuery above, inside change function where other if statements are:

```
if(this.id=='row1' && this.value=='1') {
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('#new_user_form *').filter(':checkbox').each(function(){
            if(this.id=='row1' && this.value=='1') {
            } else {
                $(this).attr("disabled",true);
            }
        });
    } else {
        $('#new_user_form *').filter(':checkbox').each(function(){
            if(this.id=='row1' && this.value=='1') {
            } else {
                $(this).attr("disabled",false);
            }
        });
    }
}
if(this.id=='row1' && this.value=='2') {
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('#new_user_form *').filter(':checkbox').each(function(){
            if(this.id=='row1' && this.value=='2') {
            } else {
                $(this).attr("disabled",true);
            }
        });
    } else {
        $('#new_user_form *').filter(':checkbox').each(function(){
            if(this.id=='row1' && this.value=='2') {
            } else {
                $(this).attr("disabled",false);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: let me know of any problems

Comment: ah got it will have a look now

Comment: hey @SKV I now want to assign unique id's to each of my checkboxes, numbering the 18 checkboxes from 1 to 18 in the id attribute. I tried changing the attribute name id to data-group and group respectively but that didn't work. Is there some attribute I could use to group the checkboxes row wise and then replace code snippets like this.id=='row1' to this.group='row1'?

Comment: Hello Paulie, you cannot add custom attribute to html elements, but you can use following lines of code to set and get the value using data() function.                                                  var theDiv = $('#row1').data('group', "test");
   alert(theDiv.data('group'));   http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

Comment: hey @SKV could you have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19151022/change-check-box-state-on-loading-a-page-using-php-ahead-of-other-functionality

Answer (score 1):

Hi please find tested and verified code as follows :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#new_user_form *').filter(':checkbox').change(function() {
            if(this.id=='row1' && this.value=='3' && $(this).is(':checked')) {
                $('#new_user_form *').filter(':checkbox').each(function(){
                    if(this.id=='row1' && this.value=='3') {
                    } else {
                        $(this).attr("checked",false);
                    }
                });
            }
            if((this.id=='row2' || this.id=='row3' || this.id=='row4' || this.id=='row5' || this.id=='row6') && this.value=='3') {
                var checkedId = this.id;
                var checkedOrNot = $(this).is(':checked');
                $('#new_user_form *').filter(':checkbox').each(function(){
                    if(this.id==checkedId && (this.value=='1' || this.value=='2')) {
                        if(checkedOrNot) {
                            $(this).attr("disabled",true);
                        } else {
                            $(this).attr("disabled",false);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            if((this.id=='row2' || this.id=='row3' || this.id=='row4' || this.id=='row5' || this.id=='row6') && this.value=='2') {
                var checkedId = this.id;
                var checkedOrNot = $(this).is(':checked');
                $('#new_user_form *').filter(':checkbox').each(function(){
                    if(this.id==checkedId && this.value=='1') {
                        if(checkedOrNot) {
                            $(this).attr("disabled",true);
                        } else {
                            $(this).attr("disabled",false);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form id="new_user_form">
<table id="mytb" class="table table-hover table-condensed">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="width: 25%;">Column 1</th>
                <th style="width: 25%">Column 2</th>
                <th style="width: 25%">Column 3</th>
                <th style="width: 25%">Column 4</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Row 1</td>
                <td class="vcenter"><input type="checkbox" id="row1" value="1"/></td>
        <td class="vcenter"><input type="checkbox" id="row1" value="2"/></td>
        <td class="vcenter"><input type="checkbox" id="row1" value="3"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Row 2</td>
                <td class="vcenter"><input type="checkbox" id="row2" value="1"/></td>
        <td class="vcenter"><input type="checkbox" id="row2" value="2"/></td>
        <td class="vcenter"><input type="checkbox" id="row2" value="3"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Row 3</td>
                <td class="vcenter"><input type="checkbox" id="row3" value="1"/></td>
        <td class="vcenter"><input type="checkbox" id="row3" value="2"/></td>
        <td class="vcenter"><input type="checkbox" id="row3" value="3"/></td>
            </tr>
<tr>
                <td>Row 4</td>
                <td class="vcenter"><input type="checkbox" id="row4" value="1"/></td>
        <td class="vcenter"><input type="checkbox" id="row4" value="2"/></td>
        <td class="vcenter"><input type="checkbox" id="row4" value="3"/></td>
            </tr>
<tr>
                <td>Row 5</td>
                <td class="vcenter"><input type="checkbox" id="row5" value="1"/></td>
        <td class="vcenter"><input type="checkbox" id="row5" value="2"/></td>
        <td class="vcenter"><input type="checkbox" id="row5" value="3"/></td>
            </tr>
<tr>
                <td>Row 6</td>
                <td class="vcenter"><input type="checkbox" id="row6" value="1"/></td>
        <td class="vcenter"><input type="checkbox" id="row6" value="2"/></td>
        <td class="vcenter"><input type="checkbox" id="row6" value="3"/></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Copy paste and enjoy :) cheers

Comment: Hey @SKV thank you so much! Two conditions don't seem to be working though: (1-> Selecting the checkbox at row 1, Column 4 does not disable all the other checkboxes) (2-> Selecting the checkbox at Row 1 Column 3 does not disable the checkbox at Row 1 Column 2)

Comment: Got 2 to work. If you could help me with 1 that would be great.

Comment: i though you said that the column 2,3,4,5,6 shold show such behavior.. you have written above If I select a checkbox from any other row, that is row 2,3,4,5 or 6 where value=2 then I need to disable the checkbox in the same row where value=1.

Comment: just add this.id=='row1' ||  on line 18 and 31 in above code, that will do the needful.

Comment: more info change if((this.id=='row2' || this.id=='row3' || this.id=='row4' || this.id=='row5' || this.id=='row6') && this.value=='3') { to if((this.id=='row1' || this.id=='row2' || this.id=='row3' || this.id=='row4' || this.id=='row5' || this.id=='row6') && this.value=='3') {

Comment: Slight modification, here's what's left:

If any one of the following check boxes are selected (row 1 column 2) or (row 1 column 3) or (row 1 column 4) all other check boxes should be disabled.

Comment: sorry about that, playing around with what you posted. If you can help me with the slight modification comment I just posted that would be great.

Comment: yes vertically, in fact everything except that particular check box should be disabled. So other check boxes in the same row and all the check boxes in the other rows.

Comment: can't see what you just posted, could you post those lines again?

Answer (score 0):

Jquery code:

```
 $('#chkPersonalDetails').click(function () {
        var checkedStatus = this.checked;
        $('span[rel=pe]').find('input').attr("checked", checkedStatus);
    });
```

ASPX code.

```
  <asp:CheckBox ID="chkPersonalDetails" runat="server" Text="Personal Details" 
    rel="pe"/>
     <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSearchAddress" runat="server" Text="Address"
      rel="pe"/>
     <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSearchPhone" runat="server" Text="Phone"
       rel="pe"/>
      <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSearchSex" runat="server" Text="Sex" rel="pe"/>
```

So what I am doing is selecting all the checkboxes that have the rel attribute as 
rel=pre I am checking or unchecking based on the first check box.

So accordingly use this code as per your requirement. Hope you got me!!

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this: http://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/.

An attempt without checking the actual checkbox ID but based on the position of the DOM is:

```
$( ":checkbox" ).on('click', function(e){
   var originatingCheckbox = this;
   var siblings =$(originatingCheckbox).parentUntil('tr').find(":checkbox");
   siblings.each(function(e){
      if(originatingCheckbox != this)
      {
         if(originatingCheckbox.checked){
            this.checked = false;
            $(this).attr("disabled", true);
         }else{
            $(this).removeAttr("disabled");
         }
      }
   });
});
```

However an HTML document should have elements with unique IDs, use name instead, name attribute can be repeated.

You can alternatively also use `document.getElementsByName('row1')` which will return an array of elements matching that name. You could do a simple loop to check which value each have and if they are checked.