# Change check box state on loading a page using PHP ahead of other functionality

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Ok so what I'm doing has several parts associated with it.

Below are the steps involved:

1. I load a table of checkboxes using PHP (there's a table with 9 rows (identified by id from 4 to 12) and 3 columns (identified with value 1 to 3))
2. Once I load the page, the state of the checkboxes needs to change. If certain checkboxes are checked then certain others need to be disabled.
3. I use a jquery change function to see which checkboxes have been checked or unchecked. Here I disable or enable the  checkboxes using the same logic in step 2 depending on the user selection.
4. Each time a check box is checked or unchecked once the page has loaded I generate a JSON, push it into an array and post it to another page by clicking a submit button.

So I'm good with the steps 1,3 and 4. I need help with changing the state of the checkbox once the page has loaded.

How do I get the same logic I'm using to disable checkboxes, once there is a change in the checkbox state to work once the page has loaded?

Here's my JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var obj = {};
        var obj1 = {};
        var array = new Array();
        $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {

        if((this.id=='5' || this.id=='6' || this.id=='7' || this.id=='8' || this.id=='9' || this.id=='10' || this.id=='11' || this.id=='12') && this.value=='1') {
                var checkedId = this.id;
                var checkedOrNot = $(this).is(':checked');
                $("input[type='checkbox']").each(function() {
                    if(this.id==checkedId && (this.value=='2' || this.value=='3')) {
                        if(checkedOrNot) {
                            $(this).attr("disabled",true);
                        } else {
                            $(this).attr("disabled",false);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }



        if((this.id=='5' || this.id=='6' || this.id=='7' || this.id=='8' || this.id=='9' || this.id=='10' || this.id=='11' || this.id=='12') && this.value=='2') {
                var checkedId = this.id;
                var checkedOrNot = $(this).is(':checked');
                $("input[type='checkbox']").each(function() {
                    if(this.id==checkedId && (this.value=='1' || this.value=='3')) {
                        if(checkedOrNot) {
                            $(this).attr("disabled",true);
                        } else {
                            $(this).attr("disabled",false);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }



        if((this.id=='5' || this.id=='6' || this.id=='7' || this.id=='8' || this.id=='9' || this.id=='10' || this.id=='11' || this.id=='12') && this.value=='3') {
                var checkedId = this.id;
                var checkedOrNot = $(this).is(':checked');
                $("input[type='checkbox']").each(function() {
                    if(this.id==checkedId && (this.value=='1' || this.value=='2')) {
                        if(checkedOrNot) {
                            $(this).attr("disabled",true);
                        } else {
                            $(this).attr("disabled",false);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }



if(this.id=='4' && this.value=='1') {
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
                $("input[type='checkbox']").each(function(){
            if(this.id=='4' && this.value=='1') {
            } else {
                $(this).attr("disabled",true);
            }
       });
    } else {
         $("input[type='checkbox']").each(function(){
            if(this.id=='4' && this.value=='1') {
            } else {
                $(this).attr("disabled",false);
            }
        });
    }
}


if(this.id=='4' && this.value=='2') {
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
                $("input[type='checkbox']").each(function(){
            if(this.id=='4' && this.value=='2') {
            } else {
                $(this).attr("disabled",true);
            }
       });
    } else {
         $("input[type='checkbox']").each(function(){
            if(this.id=='4' && this.value=='2') {
            } else {
                $(this).attr("disabled",false);
            }
        });
    }
}


if(this.id=='4' && this.value=='3') {
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
                $("input[type='checkbox']").each(function(){
            if(this.id=='4' && this.value=='3') {
            } else {
                $(this).attr("disabled",true);
            }
       });
    } else {
         $("input[type='checkbox']").each(function(){
            if(this.id=='4' && this.value=='3') {
            } else {
                $(this).attr("disabled",false);
            }
        });
    }
}
   //Other functionality
 });  });
```

**UPDATE**

The PHP table is as such:

```
<?php
    foreach($a as $b) {
        if ($s["id"]== $b["c"]) {
            if($b["p"] == "e") {
                        echo '<td class="vcenter"><input type="checkbox" id="'.$s["id"].'" value="1" checked/></td>';
            }else {

                        echo '<td class="vcenter"><input type="checkbox" id="'.$s["id"].'" value="1"/></td>';
            }   
            if($b["p"] == "r") {
                        echo '<td class="vcenter"><input type="checkbox" id="'.$s["id"].'" value="2" checked/></td>';
            }else {
                        echo '<td class="vcenter"><input type="checkbox" id="'.$s["id"].'" value="2"/></td>';
            }
            if($b["p"] == "b") {
                        echo '<td class="vcenter"><input type="checkbox" id="'.$s["id"].'" value="3" checked/></td>';
            }else {
                        echo '<td class="vcenter"><input type="checkbox" id="'.$s["id"].'" value="3"/></td>';
            }
        }else {
            echo '<td class="vcenter"><input type="checkbox" id="'.$s["id"].'" value="1"/></td>';
            echo '<td class="vcenter"><input type="checkbox" id="'.$s["id"].'" value="2"/></td>';
            echo '<td class="vcenter"><input type="checkbox" id="'.$s["id"].'" value="3"/></td>';
        }
    }

?>
```

The id values vary from 4 to 12.

The conditions are as such:

If any check box in row 5 to 12 are selected then all other check boxes in the same row should get disabled.

If any check box in the first row is selected then all the other check boxes in the table should get disabled.

**ANOTHER UPDATE**

So the check boxes will have the following values: [id:value]

```
[4,1]    [4,2]  [4,3]
[5,1]    [5,2]  [5,3]
[6,1]    [6,2]  [6,3]
[7,1]    [7,2]  [7,3]
[8,1]    [8,2]  [8,3]
[9,1]    [9,2]  [9,3]
[10,1]   [10,2]  [10,3]
[11,1]   [11,2]  [11,3]
[12,1]   [12,2]  [12,3]
```

There are varied possibilities so you may assume any check box is selected. But all the conditions should hold.

**YET ANOTHER UPDATE:**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$("input[type='checkbox']").each(function() { 
 if($(this).attr("checked",true))
 {
        var id = mainid; 
        var value = this.value;
        var idn = this.id;
        if(id == "4") {
            $("input[type='checkbox']").each(function() {
                $(this).attr("disabled",true);
            });
        } else {
            $("input[type='checkbox']").each(function() {
                if(this.value == value) {
                    $(this).attr("disabled",true);
                    idn = ++id;
                }
            });
        }
}
});
});
```

Comment: If it's on page load and you are using php to determine if the checkbox is checked then you should probably use the same logic to determine if the other fields should be disabled.

Comment: yes that's the plan. I need help with implementing that.

Comment: Then why did you post your javascript instead of php?

Comment: PHP loads the the check box data based on another submission on the page. Then I need to disable certain checkboxes. Then look for a change in the checkbox state.

Comment: Hi Paulie, can i have the table structure also and also one condition that work once page loaded..

Comment: have a look at my update.

Comment: please also provide $a and $s array content, so i can recreate the page at my end.

Comment: sorry I can't do that :( I'll add some more details to the update, as much as I can.

Comment: added more details, have a look. I'm trying to play around with jquery .load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use following code for your use, demonstration as follows :

Suppose you get following values to be selected from database

```
<?php
    $arrayIds = array("5"=>"1");
    //where 5 is id of the check box and 1 is value
?>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
     <?php foreach($arrayIds as $key => $val ) { ?>
        var id = <?php echo $key; ?>;
        var value = <?php echo $val; ?>;
        var idn = id;
        if(id == "4") {
            $("input[type='checkbox']").each(function() {
                $(this).attr("disabled",true);
            });
        } else {
            $("input[type='checkbox']").each(function() {
                //alert(this.id+"--"+this.value+"--"+id+"--"+value+"--"+idn);
                //if(this.id == idn && this.value == value) {
                if(this.value == value) {
                    $(this).attr("disabled",true);
                    idn = ++id;
                }
            });
        }
     <?php } ?>
 });
</script>
```

Above script will disable all the checkboxes with value 1 i.e first row in above case.

if we get following

```
<?php
    $arrayIds = array("4"=>"1");
    //where 5 is id of the check box and 1 is value
?>
Above script will disable all the checkboxes found on the page.

hope this will help you complete your work
```

## Update

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[type='checkbox']").each(function() { 
        if($(this).attr("checked",true))  {
            var id = mainid; 
            var value = this.value;
            var idn = this.id;
            if(id == "4") {
                $("input[type='checkbox']").each(function() {
                    $(this).attr("disabled",true);
                });
            } else {
                $("input[type='checkbox']").each(function() {
                    if(this.value == value) {
                        $(this).attr("disabled",true);
                        idn = ++id;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

you need to define mainid though..

Comment: i'm playing around with this to integrate it would the code that I can't share. I'll get back to you asap.

Comment: no luck so far. any suggestions as to how I can select all the checkboxes present with jquery?

Comment: you can use $("input[type='checkbox']").each(function() {
      $(this).attr("checked",true);
     });

Comment: ah yes i needed to add this -> $(this).attr("checked",true); I'll check it out now :)

Comment: have a look at YET ANOTHER UPDATE. could you tell me if there is a syntax error? It isn't working.

Comment: I have defined mainid. It works with my other functionality but still no luck.

Comment: ok some success :) except that no matter the input all the checkboxes are getting disabled. I will try to solve it from here.

Comment: actually you have looped it wrongly the top php loop that was in my code was coming from db and it works once for an entry for ex if array("6" => "1"); is the content it works on ly once.. but in you case you are looping thrice for all checkboxes... try using alerts in loop for debuging

Comment: all the checkboxes seem to be getting selected and then disabled.

Comment: must be a conflict b/w your code selecting them and disabling them... may be both getting executed.

Comment: nope :( found some basic problem though will keep at it till I figure it out.

Comment: problem solved :) played around with it quite a bit and it works now. thanks for your help @SKV

Comment: great to hear :) care to vote up and acceptance so anybody else can take reference from here..