# display data on selecting a checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, checkbox

I have 3 checkboxes

```
<input type="checkbox" name ="chk[]" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="Permanent">Permanent
<input type="checkbox" name ="chk[]" id="inlineCheckbox2" value="Drive">Drive
<input type="checkbox" name ="chk[]" id="inlineCheckbox3" value="Contract"> Contract
```

and a div that contains 2 inputs

```
<div id="datetime"> 
    <input type='text' class="form-control" name="datee">
    <input type='text' class="form-control" name="timee" >
</div>
```

Checkbox `Permanent` and `Contract` can be selected normally, but i want that till the time Drive checkbox is not selected, the div should stay disabled, when the user selects Drive, he should be able to select values from div and if he again unchecks the Drive checkbox the div should get disabled again.

I tried to follow this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18912096/on-selecting-a-checkbox-disable-spefic-checkboxes) but it didnt seemed to work for me, can anyone please tell how it can be done

Comment: I would suggest you try the `.show()` and `.hide()` methods, but they can make modelling the page tricky. Nevertheless, it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could disable/enable the time controls like this:

```
function setDateTimeAvailability() {
    var checked = $("#inlineCheckbox2").is(':checked');
    $("#datetime input").attr('disabled', !checked);
    // Or, if you prefer to hide, do:
    //     $("#datetime").toggle(checked);
}
$("#inlineCheckbox2").change(setDateTimeAvailability);

// Make sure on page load the datetime availability is set correctly
$(setDateTimeAvailability);
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kx3ubwhr/).

Comment: This is the best answer among all +10.

Comment: `$("#inlineCheckbox2").on("change",setDateTimeAvailability).change();`

Comment: @mplungjan, why trigger `change` again? It was already triggered by the user interaction, and `setDateTimeAvailability` does nothing that requires to fire it.

Comment: @trincot make sure to trigger it on load - so attach the event handler and trigger it. That is how to do it

Comment: @mplungjan, I disagree, the checkbox's value is not changed on load. It is an attribute that is set, but that has nothing to do with a `change` event.

Comment: You say it yourself! When the page loads, run the change event in case the page is reloaded. I do know what I am talking about. What's the point of your `// Make sure on page load the datetime availability is set correctly $(setDateTimeAvailability);` my suggestion is to chain the event instead

Comment: I really hesitate to do that, because the change event represents a signal that the user changed the checked/not-checked status of a check box, which is not the case on page load, and which the call to `setDateTimeAvailability` is not doing either. You might as well then go through all the inputs on the page to trigger a change event for each on page load. Is that your intention?

Comment: Yes, but you put `this` in the function, which makes no sense when called by passing a function reference. No wonder it does not work. I took your fiddle and [made one change](http://jsfiddle.net/o9uLraLa/5/) which shows what I think should be done: call the function, but don't trigger the event.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#inlineCheckbox2").change(function() {
    //dissable if check box not selected
    var dissable = !$(this).is(':checked');
    //set all .form-controls dissabled
    $('.form-control').each(function() {

      $(this).attr('disabled', dissable);
    });

  });

  //set initail status
  $("#inlineCheckbox2").trigger("change");

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="Permanent">Permanent
<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" id="inlineCheckbox2" value="Drive">Drive
<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" id="inlineCheckbox3" value="Contract">Contract

<div id="datetime">
  <input type='text' class="form-control" name="datee">
  <input type='text' class="form-control" name="timee">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

> **Required Library:** <script
>   src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js">

```
$(function() {
    HideDiv();
});

$("#inlineCheckbox2").on('change', function() {
    HideDiv();
});

function HideDiv() {
    if ($("#inlineCheckbox2").is(':checked')) {
        $("#datetime").show();
    } else {
        $("#datetime").hide();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code :

```
    <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.0.min.js"></script> 
    </head>
    <body>
       <input type="checkbox" name ="chk[]" id="inlineCheckbox1"  value="Permanent">Permanent
       <input type="checkbox" name ="chk[]" id="inlineCheckbox2" value="Drive">Drive
        <input type="checkbox" name ="chk[]" id="inlineCheckbox3" value="Contract"> Contract
    <div id="datetime" style="display:none;"> 
        <input type='text' class="form-control" name="datee">
        <input type='text' class="form-control" name="timee" >
    </div>
 <script>
    $("#inlineCheckbox2").change(function(){

       if($(this).is(':checked')){
            $("#datetime").show();
        } else{
            $("#datetime").hide();
        }
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this one:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".form-control").prop('disabled', true);
    $('#inlineCheckbox2').change(function(){

        var checked = $("#inlineCheckbox2").is(':checked');
        if (checked == true)
        {
            $(".form-control").prop('disabled', false);
        }
        else
        {
            $(".form-control").prop('disabled', true);
        }
    });
});
```

[Check Here](http://jsfiddle.net/p5ebz625/)

Answer (score 0):

The shortest way to do this (in terms of code text) is to give the Drive checkbox a jQuery script to run when its value is changed:

```
onchange=$('#datetime').children().prop('disabled',
!$(this).prop('checked'))
```

And let the date and time inputs be disabled when the document loads.