# ASP.net MVC 4 Validation Within bootstrap Modal and PartialView

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, twitter-bootstrap

In my application I was using simple View the Validation, both client and server side validation, was working fine, but now I have changed to bootstrap modal and PartialView. 
 The problem is that Client Side Validation dosn't work any more and for server side validation when I click submit he redirect me to new page (see picture) instead of showing the error on the current modal pop-up.
[image]

`Create Controller` :

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.CAT_ID = new SelectList(db.CATEGORIE, "CAT_ID", "LIBELLE");
            ViewBag.C_GARANT = new SelectList(db.GARANTIE, "C_GARANT", "LIB_ABREGE");
            return PartialView("_Create");
        }

        //
        // POST: /Taux/Create

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(TAUX taux)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.TAUX.Add(taux);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            ViewBag.CAT_ID = new SelectList(db.CATEGORIE, "CAT_ID", "LIBELLE", taux.CAT_ID);
            ViewBag.C_GARANT = new SelectList(db.GARANTIE, "C_GARANT", "LIB_ABREGE", taux.C_GARANT);
            return PartialView("_Create", taux);
        }
```

`_Create` Partial View :

```
@model pfebs0.Models.TAUX
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="CreateTaux">Add</h3>
</div>
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)


    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">
           <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Categorie">Categorie : </label>
            @Html.DropDownList("CAT_ID", String.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CAT_ID)
           </div>
           //Other Form input.
      </div>
       <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
       </div>
}

</div>
     <script>
            $("select").addClass("form-control");
            $("input").addClass("form-control");
            $("label").addClass("control-label");
    </script>
 @section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval") }
```

`Index View` where I puted the modal :

```
<p>
       @Html.ActionLink("Ajouter", "Create", "Taux",
                new { id = "btnAdd", @class="btn btn-default"})
</p

        <div id="modalDiv" class="modal fade" >
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                </div>
        </div>
    @section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

        $('#btnAdd').click(function () {
            $('.modal-dialog').load(this.href, function () {
                $('#modalDiv').modal({
                    backdrop: 'static',
                    keyboard: true
                }, 'show');
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
 </script> }
```

So what I have to add or change to Have client validation in my modal and for server validation to be redirected to modal, instead new page like in picture ?

Comment: I think you'll need to re-parse validators for your new HTML elements loaded dinamically: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6691958/unobtrusive-jquery-validation-on-elements-created-by-javascript-mvc3 Also, you might need to set your `Html.BeginForm` to something like `Html.BeginForm(action, controller, method, null)` to avoid weird query string.

Comment: @ALMMa thank's for validation I resolved this problem, but steel the redirection problem how to slove it ?

Comment: @Chlebta have you ever got this resolved where it does not redirect you to the new page and actually displays the server side validation? I am having the same issue.

Comment: @Chlebta Did you resolve the client side validation issue and redirect to  new page without modal ( only view page ) and actually display the server side validation errors in modal ? I am having the same issue in July 2017 ( 3 years later ).

Answer (score 0):

You can rely on the built in bootstrap functionality of the role and data-target attributes. If you define your modal's role as "dialog" and give it an id then you can reference that in a HTML button with a data-target and data-toggle attributes.

You also need to avoid loading your _Create partial from an ajax request. Just load it along with Index using @Html.Partial. It will not appear in your view if the attributes are set correctly.

Here are the steps I did to get it working:

First modify your _Index to load partial view and update your modalDiv to define a role.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalDiv" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
 @Html.Partial("~/{PathToView}/_Create.cshtml", new pfebs0.Models.TAUX())
</div>
```

Now instead of using @HtmlActionLink and JavaScript to load dialog, create a button as follows. Make sure to remove the JS click event code.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalDiv">Ajouter</button>
```

Now bootstrap will handle showing and hiding dialog automatically with the defined role and data attributes and MVC validation will appear correctly. You can leave your controller code as-is.